# What is the effect of giving everything position relative?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

I was looking at some example CSS / HTML and found this:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    position: relative;
}
```

It seems that this rule will change the layout significantly.

What is the thinking behind this rule?

Comment: Basically nothing unless positioning values are used. It does have the effect of forcing (I believe) a z-index calculation but in general it's pointless.

Comment: what effect do you expect while giving everything position relative? as these things to be aware of it...

Comment: That will have lots of effects (probably more than is reasonable to go into in a Stackoverflow answer) and I can't think of any which I would consider "good". I can't tell you what the person who wrote that was thinking, but they probably didn't think (and know about CSS) *enough*.

Comment: @Quentin I know my CSS and disagree - I would like to hear what downsides of enabling positioning by default you are thinking of. I can think of only one situation where I would use static (making a child relate to it's parent parent).

Answer (score -2):

You can specified every element position (top, left, right, bottom) from current position to which you need. Sample I need elm goes top for 10px:

```
elm.myclass {position: relative; top: -10px;}
```

For better position specification use [display:flex;](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)